# How to get a workitem by id in TFS 2013 web access when writing custom controls?

Tags: custom-controls, tfs-web-access

I have built an incomplete extension for TFS Webaccess 2013 in javascript.
I want to modify combobox input based on linked work item types.  For instance - User Story 555 is currently in active state, and I would like to prevent users from changing to a closed state by greying out the option in the combobox IF a linked child element is still active.  I can grey out the item, but I cannot figure out how to get the state of the linked child workitem.

I'm able to say the following in javascript to get the ID of the first linked workitem:

`var itemID = workitem.allLinks[0].linkData.ID;`

I'm calling this within the bind() function, where workitem is passed as a parameter.  I need the ability to grab the state of the child workitem, but have been unsuccessful so far.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please use

```
workItem.getLinks()
```

instead of allLinks since all links may include removed links as well.

Then you can access a work item by id using following async call:

```
workItem.store.beginGetWorkItem(linkedWorkItemId, function(linkedWorkItem) {
    var state = linkedWorkItem.getFieldValue("System.State");
    // Use state here..
});
```